# Is there a way of locking a resource group so that it can’t be deleted without unlocking it?

Tags: azure, azure-resource-group

We often delete resource groups.  I have one resource group that I would like to protect.  Is there a way of “locking” it so that I would be required to unlock it before being allowed to delete it?  Bonus points if it requires a password.

Answer (score 1):

Egads.  Yes there is.  Sorry I didn’t see this earlier.  Simply go the the Resource Group’s properties and click on **Lock** and add a new lock and set the type to **Delete**

Answer (score 1):

**You achieve this using following steps:**

Open you resource group.

In the Settings blade for the resource, resource group, or subscription that you wish to lock, select Locks.

To add a lock, select Add. If you want to create a lock at a parent level, select the parent. The currently selected resource inherits the lock from the parent. For example, you could lock the resource group to apply a lock to all its resources.

Give the lock a name and lock level. Optionally, you can add notes that describe the lock.

[image]

For more details, refer : [Lock resources to prevent unexpected changes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-lock-resources)